# C# ExponentialBackOff to Timespan Polly

Tags: c#, polly, retry-logic

I'm replacing my currenty retry policies with the Polly framework. I used to define my retry strategy like this:

```
var strategy = new ExponentialBackoff(RetryStrategy.DefaultClientRetryCount, RetryStrategy.DefaultMinBackoff, RetryStrategy.DefaultMaxBackoff, RetryStrategy.DefaultClientBackoff);
```

where the `DefaultClientRetryCount` is the number of retries
and then the exponentialBackoff calculates the sleep time between the retries based on the variables: `DefaultMinBackoff` is the min timespan between retries; `DefaultMaxBackoff` is the maximum timespan; and `DefaultClientBackoff` is a default value used to calculate a random delta between retries.

On Polly I define my retryPolicy like this:

```
var retryPolicy = Policy.Handle<Exception>(ex => _transientErrorDetectionStrategy.IsTransient(ex)).WaitAndRetryAsync(int retryCount, Func<int,timespan> sleepDuration);
```

Where the `retryCount` is the number of retries and the `sleepDuration` is the time between retries.

How can I replicate the Timespan between retries generated on the previous policy to send as parameter to the `WaitAndRetryAsync` method on Polly?

Comment: Polly documents various ways of implementing exponential backoff [here](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry#exponential-backoff). For some randomisation, Polly documentation gives examples with jitter [here](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry-with-jitter).

Comment: To answer the question "How to replicate the Timespan between retries generated by the previous policy?", we need to know exactly how the parameter `DefaultClientBackoff` was used to calculate a random delta between retries.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Polly.Contrib.WaitAndRetry](https://github.com/Polly-Contrib/Polly.Contrib.WaitAndRetry) library... `DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2` specifically, which can be described as follows (per their documentation):

> Generates sleep durations in an exponentially backing-off, jittered manner, making
> sure to mitigate any correlations. For example: 850ms, 1455ms, 3060ms. Per discussion
> in Polly issue 530, the jitter of this implementation exhibits fewer spikes and
> a smoother distribution than the AWS jitter formula.

This helper will generate the delay that your looking for with an added benefit of having all the kinks and bugs worked out. Thanks in advance to the awesome Polly community!  Once you have the delay, you can turn around and define your policy with it:

```
var maxDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45);
var delay = Backoff.DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2(
    medianFirstRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), retryCount: 50)
        .Select(s => TimeSpan.FromTicks(Math.Min(s.Ticks, maxDelay.Ticks)));

var retryPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<FooException>()
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(delay);
```

PS: this helper method has 2 other optional parameters:

> seed: An optional System.Random seed to use. If not specified, will use a shared instance with a random seed, per Microsoft recommendation for maximum randomness.

> fastFirst: Whether the first retry will be immediate or not.